# Use values in R dataframe as index to subset and summarize another dataframe?

Tags: r

I want to create a new column in dataframe x, whose value is the mean of the start and end rows in dataframe y. I can do this in a loop, but is there a functional approach that would be faster with big data?

```
set.seed(1)
x <- data.frame(start = seq(1, 3, 2))
x$end <- x$start + 1

#  start end
#1     1   2
#2     3   4

y <- data.frame(value = runif(4))

#      value
#1 0.2655087
#2 0.3721239
#3 0.5728534
#4 0.9082078

# one way to do it
for (i in 1:nrow(x)){
    x[i, 'mean.value'] <- mean(y$value[x[i,'start']:x[i,'end']])}

# desired result
  start end mean.value
1     1   2  0.3188163
2     3   4  0.7405306 

# could something like this work?
x['mean.value'] <- lapply(x, function(k){???})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with `Map` to get the sequence of index from the 'x' columns, subset the 'value' column of 'y' based on that, get the `mean` and create the 'mean.value' column in 'x'

```
x['mean.value'] <- sapply(do.call(Map, c(f = `:`, x)), function(x) mean(y$value[x]))
#
#     start end mean.value
#1     1   2  0.3188163
#2     3   4  0.7405306
```

---

It can be also simplified as

```
x['mean.value'] <- mapply(function(i, j)  mean(y$value[i:j]),  x$start, x$end)
```

---

A similar option with `tidyverse` would be to use `map2` (from `purrr`)

```
library(tidyverse)
x %>%
    mutate(mean.value = map2_dbl(start, end, ~  mean(y$value[.x:.y])))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `sapply` by looping over each row in `x` we subset the corresponding rows from `y` and take the `mean` of them.

```
x$mean_value <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(x)), function(i) mean(y[unlist(x[i,]),]))
x

#  start end mean_value
#1     1   2  0.3188163
#2     3   4  0.7405306
```